# Typescript convert a type described by an Interface to another?

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, casting, type-conversion

I know that types exists for a reason.

But my collegues'd like to hide the leaky abstraction i have in one of my component.
I am using a big config interface to hold all the information my main component needs to work and one of the properties is an array or listable elements that'll form a multiselect.
Basically my array has a type like this:

```
export interface Column {
  label: string;
  property: string;
}
```

But we are using a 3rd party [multiselect component](https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect), which accepts only it's own typed array as options. Like:

```
export interface IMultiSelectOption {
  id: any;
  name: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  isLabel?: boolean;
  parentId?: any;
  params?: any;
  classes?: string;
  image?: string;
}
```

In our case `id -> property`, and `name -> label`.
But!
In order for the select option to work it needs to have this key-value pairs to work.

How can I convert our own type to the type of the expected multiselect to work? I can't just make another list as type `IMultiselectOption` b/c that wouldn't solve the leaky abstraction issue.
I cannot convert it in my recieving component where all the magic happens (basically this is the curtain that hides all the magic) b/c type `Column[]` props doesn't exists on type `IMultiselectOption[]`

Comment: Has you think create a custom Form Control that "mask" the multiselect component?

Comment: @Eliseo wouldn't that be redundant to bundle a component into a custom form control just for this purpose?

Comment: The other idea I had was a getter that transform your columns in options, but then in (change) you need transform the result to change your columns

Answer (score 1):

In my case I also had to use several type for the same data, but represented/organised diferently for frontend and backend uses.

I just have a Helper Service conversion where I convert my Object like so:

```
ColumnToIMultiSelectOption(column: Column): IMultiSelectOption {
   return <IMultiSelectOption>{
      id: column.property,
      name: column.label,
   }
}
```

Comment: the issue with this is that i have to deliver the modified type through the config i am using and since it's tied to Column i can't really make a change like this i think.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved by embedding the 3rd party component into another helper component. This way I was able to manipulate the data and tweak it as multiselect component needs it.
Thanks to @Eliseo this idea was the winner.

Nothing fancy. Just a 3 input 1 output component which emits the changes then listens to them in the consuming component.